# jq slurp and add key / value pairs

Tags: json, jq

`$DATA` is a long string containing some Email addresses.

```
echo "$DATA" | grep -Eo "\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}\b" | sort | uniq | jq --slurp --raw-input 'split("\n")[:-1]'
```

Output:

```
[
  "email1@mydomain.com",
  "email2@mydomain.com",
  "email3@mydomain.com",
  "email4@mydomain.com"
]
```

Desired Output:

```
[
  {
    "email": "email1@mydomain.com",
    "free": "0",
    "used": "0"
  },
  {
    "email": "email2@mydomain.com",
    "free": "0",
    "used": "0"
  },
  {
    "email": "email3@mydomain.com",
    "free": "0",
    "used": "0"
  },
  {
    "email": "email4@mydomain.com",
    "free": "0",
    "used": "0"
  }
]
```

I guess it should be something like `+= {"free": "0"}`

Comment: It would be easier to answer if you posted your current `jq` command's input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace your current `jq` command by the following :

```sh
jq --slurp --raw-input 'split("\n")[:-1] | map({email: ., free: 0, used: 0})'
```

You can [try it here](https://jqplay.org/s/5nbgJmJGbo).